# Google Maps in the app doesn't show correct location

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, google

I have a customer with a website with Google Maps embedded for school location tracking. Sometimes the school appears in far corners and not exactly where it should be. For example, I copy pasted the exact location of one of the schools from Google Maps to the app's longitude and latitude fields to display the exact location in the Google Maps present within the app, but it always shows the school far away from the exact location. I have to manually play around with latitudes and longitudes every time to bring the pointer to the near location, which is a lot of work. It rounds off the figure for both fields. Not sure if there is a solution exists for this.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works